# CNN: why it is making no difference whether i measure accuracy by logits or softmax layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

While measuring the accuracy of a CNN i understand that i should use the output of the softmax layer(Predicted label) to target label. But even if i compare logits (which are the output of last fully connected layer, as per my understanding) with target labels, i get almost same accuracy. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
matches = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred,1),tf.argmax(y,1))   
acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches,tf.float32))
```

whereas y_pred is the output of final normal fully connected layer without any activation function (only matrix multiplication and bias addition w*x+b)

```
y_pred = normal_full_layer(second_hidden_layer,6)
```

**6** because I have 6 classes.

Here is the accuracy graph using `y_pred`:
[image: Using only Logits]

**Accuracy is around 96%**

Now if I do same (calculate accuracy) by applying softmax activation on `y_pred`, let's call it `pred_softmax`, i get almost same accuracy

```
pred_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(y_pred).
```

**Accuracy** Graph using softmax:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the accuracy should be exactly equal. Taking the argmax of an array of logits should return the same as taking the argmax of the softmax of that array. This is because the softmax function maps larger logits to be closer to 1 in a strictly increasing way.

The softmax function takes a set of outputs (an array) `y` and maps it to `exp(y)/sum(exp(y))`, the larger the `y[i]` the larger the softmax of `y[i]` and so it must be that `argmax(y[i])==argmax(softmax(y[i]))`